# Image not displaying in span

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my span in html

```
 <span id="spProgress" runat="server"></span>
```

Now i have 2 javascript functions, one to display a loading indicator

```
  function DisablePage()
{
     document.getElementById('<%= spProgress.ClientID %>').innerHTML="<img src='Images/updateProgress.gif' />";
}
```

Another function to hide it.

```
function EnablePage()
{
    document.getElementById('<%= spProgress.ClientID %>').innerHTML='';
}
```

When i click a button it works perfectly fine on local system.But when i put it on production server the image is not displayed.I have checked the image url but its perfectly fine.
The surprising thing is that when i click on the button it does'nt display but if i download a file from my web application, then after that the image starts displaying properly.

Here is my client script code for download

```
function hidePage()
{
    eraseCookie("DStatus");
    EnableMe();
}
function EnableMe()
{      
    var hddCdrDownloadRecordsLimit='<%=this.hddCdrDownloadRecordsLimit.ClientID %>';
    var hddTotalCount='<%=this.hddTotalCount.ClientID %>';

  if((document.getElementById(hddCdrDownloadRecordsLimit).value) < (document.getElementById(hddTotalCount).value))
    {
        DisablePage();
        document.getElementById('<%=this.btnSearch.ClientID %>').disabled=true;
    } 
    else 
    {
       DisablePage();
    } 
var downLoadStatus = readCookie("DStatus");
if (downLoadStatus == "Completed")
{
    EnablePage();
    document.getElementById('<%=this.btnSearch.ClientID %>').disabled=false;
}
else
{
 setTimeout("EnableMe()", 6000);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "if i download a file from my web application"?

Comment: @Maciej i have a download button in my web application page which downloads the data displayed in that pages Grid

Comment: Can you clear out your browser's cache and see if you can reproduce the problem locally?

Comment: i just cleared the cache but still its working fine locally..

Comment: I think the cause of the problem is that when you append the HTML to your span, your browser is not making a request for the image. Try @ismails suggestion. his approach loads the image on the initial request but hides it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to load image at page load, putting your image tag inside span and just work with "show" or "hide" that element.

```
<span id="spProgress" runat="server" style="display:none;"><img src='Images/updateProgress.gif' /></span>
```

Create a function that changes the style of span element to show (display:block) or hide (display:none).

Hope that help.

Comment: well this time the image gets displayed properly, but problem is its a gif and its not working, i mean the image is not working as gif(not revolving as it must..)

Answer (score 0):

have you check that the html is being appended into the span? I would use CHrome or firebug to inspect the element and then click on the open url in new tab to see the full url it is using for the image. It could be that it has the wrong directory online and you need to but ./Images first etc

Comment: in that case why does it get corrected once i click the download button on my page which downloads the data from that page,

Comment: true, but I would still use inspector to see if the html has been appened into the span element and also check the spans attributes that it is not hidden etc